# Awesome WM help popup messed up (possible soluction with new function)

Tags: linux, window-managers, awesome-wm

**NOTE:** I just started to use awesome not very long ago, and don't really know the lua programming language.

I cloned [HikariKnight's awesome theme](https://github.com/HikariKnight/material-awesome) and started to customize the hotkeys. I have a logitech keyboard that has some launcher keys that will open you default apps (on windows that is). I wanted to make them open the default apps here, so I edited the config. Now the help menu has the name of some of the keys repeated over and over for no apparent reason.

[image: messed up awesomewm help popup]

If anyone could help me fix this that would be awesome.

**Possible Solution(?)**

I might be able to use the `new` function to use the `hide_without_description` option. This wouldn't be ideal though as it would just remove the hotkey from the help menu.

I found the documentation for it [here](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.hotkeys_popup.widget.html#new), but don't know how to use the `new` function.

Comment: `XF86Search` does not seem to appear in that repo anywhere: https://github.com/HikariKnight/material-awesome/search?q=XF86Search so these key bindings must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @UliSchlachter I added those keybindings to make use of the extra keys on my keyboard. And the keybindings work, I just would like to make it so that it doesn't repeat the key like you see in the picture.

Comment: Well, *how* did you add them? Seems like you added them quite often.

Comment: @UliSchlachter You can see my code in [this](https://github.com/bobsfriend12/material-awesome) github repo. All I did was copy and paste the other keybindings, and then change the keys and the command. The file with the keybindings is in `configuration/keys/global.lua`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/awesomewm/comments/mgqq95/messed_up_help_menu/gszd5u0/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

To quote PlatformKnuckles:

> I think I see the problem. Check the line in the keybindings file:
>
> > for i = 1, 9 do
>
> You're starting the keybindings in a loop multiple times.

(I didn't look at your `rc.lua` at all. I just assume the answer above is correct.)

Comment: Yeah, I made that reddit thread. Already saw that. Havn't been able to try it. If it works I will mark this as correct.